# angular bootstrap date-picker not calling function

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I want to automatically display hours after selecting date-picker between two days. I am using the angular ngb bootstrap, but whenever i select the dates, the function to do the operation is not called. i.e. (change)="onChangeDate()". Please, i need assistance to see what i am doing wrong. Here is my html and typescript. Thanks

HTML

```
         <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 form-control-label  ml-2" for="date_from">{{'From Date' | translate}} <span class="danger">*</span>:</label>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <input  type="text"  placeholder="{{todayDate | date: 'MM-dd-yyyy 08:30'}}" [max]="leaveList.date_to" class="form-control input-md" id="date_from" 
                    name="date_from"  [(ngModel)]="leaveList.date_from" ngbDatepicker  #d="ngbDatepicker"  (change)="onChangeDate()"  max="9999-12-31">
                
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button">
                      <img src="img/calendar-icon.svg" style="width: 1.2rem; height: 1rem; cursor: pointer;"/>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 mt-1">
                    <ngb-timepicker name="time_from" 
                    [seconds]="true"
                    [(ngModel)]="leaveList.time_from" id="time_from"></ngb-timepicker>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-md-12 form-control-label" for="date_to">{{'Date To'| translate}} <span class="danger"> *</span></label>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="text"  placeholder="{{todayDate | date: 'MM-dd-yyyy 16:00'}}"  [(ngModel)]="leaveList.date_to" [min]="leaveList.date_from" 
                    class="form-control input-md" id="date_to" ngbDatepicker  #f="ngbDatepicker" (change)="onChangeDate()"
                    name="date_to"  ngbDatepicker #f="ngbDatepicker" max="9999-12-31">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="f.toggle()" type="button">
                          <img src="img/calendar-icon.svg" style="width: 1.2rem; height: 1rem; cursor: pointer;"/>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 mt-1">
                    <ngb-timepicker name="time_to"  
                    [seconds]="true"
                    [(ngModel)]="leaveList.time_to" ></ngb-timepicker>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

TS FILE for the onChange() function

```
onChangeDate(){
var minutesWorked = 0;
var startDate = new Date(this.leaveList.date_from);
var endDate = new Date(this.leaveList.date_to);
if(endDate < startDate){
    return 0;
}
var current  = startDate
// Define work range
var workHoursStart = 8;
var workHoursEnd = 18;
var includeWeekends = false;
console.log("current", current.getHours()+''+current.getMinutes());
// console.log('')
// Loop while currentDate is less than end Date (by minutes)
while(current <= endDate){          
    // Is the current time within a work day (and if it 
    // occurs on a weekend or not)          
    if(current.getHours() >= workHoursStart && current.getHours() < workHoursEnd && (includeWeekends ? current.getDay() !== 0 && current.getDay() !== 6 : true)){
          minutesWorked++;
    }

    // Increment current time
    current.setTime(current.getTime() + 1000 * 60);
}

// Return the number of hours
this.leaveList.hours = Math.floor(minutesWorked / 60);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

ngbDatePicker, by defect mannage object of type NgbDateStruct, so there're nothing like

```
/** WRONG***/
var startDate = new Date(this.leaveList.date_from);
```

But you can mannage Date javascrpt object if you use as provider of NgbDateAdapter, NgbDateNativeUTCAdapter or NgbDateNativeAdapter.

You can do it in the component

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: '...',
  providers: [
    {provide: NgbDateAdapter, useClass: NgbDateNativeUTCAdapter},
  ]
})
```

or in the module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  exports: [...],
  providers: [
        {provide: NgbDateAdapter, useClass: NgbDateNativeUTCAdapter},
  ]
})
```

With that adapter, your leaveList.date_to and leaveList.date_from are yet Date object of javascript

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>change</kbd> action will only be fired after blur in the textbox, you can use <kbd>dateSelect</kbd> instead of change. Another thing is that you cannot create javascript date object directly from date_from object.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-bootstrap-datepicker-popup-exwhc1) is the working example for that.